# First order logic - Identity. Show $\vDash \forall x\exists y (x = y)$.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I want to learn math on my own and I started with logic. I am studying the book "Logic and structure" written by Dirk van Dalen. I really like his style but he doesn't give detailed explanations neither solutions to exercises. There is a small chapter in his book called Identity where he talks about the axioms (first order logic).

[The axioms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqDaf.png)

The exercises don't seem to be extremely hard, but I don't know how to prove them rigorously. ([All exercises](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3UPy.png))

1. Show $\vDash \forall x\exists y (x = y)$
2. Show $\vDash \forall x(\varphi(x) \Leftrightarrow \exists y(x = y  \land \varphi(y)))$ and $\vDash \forall x(\varphi(x) \Leftrightarrow \forall y(x = y  \implies \varphi(y)))$ where $y$ does not occur in $\varphi(x)$.

For example, the first one: $\forall x\exists y (x = y)$, seems so obvious, but I don't know if it requires a more complex proof (maybe a proof based on the axioms).

For the second exercise, do I need to use Induction on $\varphi$ ? (like van Dalen used for the second part of the 4 axiom).

[Induction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QapQ7.png)

I would really appreciate any help! (at least for the first 2 exercises so I can understand and try to solve the other ones by myself.)

Comment: It's better to write out the exercises you are asking about in the body of your question, than to ask users to go to a link offsite. Makes it easier for future visitors to find, also.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I edited the question and added the first 2 exercises.

Comment: If your aim is to learn math on your own, a textbook on logic may not be the best the place to start. The text you are using seems for suitable to someone already fairly advanced in math. If you want to learn the basic methods of proof, you might try various freeware packages that will give you instant feedback. Google: "software to learn basic methods of math proof"

Comment: @DanChristensen You are right about the book. I wanted to start with the foundations of mathematics and I searched for the best book on logic. The book is very good, but as you said, it's for people who are already fairly advanced in mathematics. I want to get another book. But I can also say that I learned a lot of things despite the book's advanced level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the given Identity Axioms:

(E1) $\forall x \exists y (x=y)$
If (E1) is not true, then Axiom I1:
$\forall x (x = x)$
will not be true. By **Contradiction**, (E1) is true.

(E2) It looks like we can not show this with **Only the Identity Axioms**; There may be more Axioms listed earlier in the Text Book, which, together with Axioms I1 & I4, must be used in (E2) here.
I think that (E2) is trying to state that variable $x$ can be substituted by variable $y$ in a statement, Provided that $y$ does not occur in the statement.
Eg $x=zx+1$ is equivalent to $y=zy+1$, but $x=yx+1$ is not equivalent to $y=yy+1$

**UPDATE:**

The first Part of (E2) can be shown via "Contradiction", with DeMorgans Laws:

$\varphi(x) \Leftrightarrow \exists x (x=y \land \varphi(y))$

When LHS is true, RHS must be true. Assume RHS is not true; then the negation is true.
$\lnot (\exists x (x=y \land \varphi(y)))$
$\forall x ( \lnot (x=y) \lor \lnot(\varphi(y)))$
$( \forall x \lnot (x=y) \lor \forall x \lnot(\varphi(y)))$

By (E1), $\forall x \lnot (x=y)$ is not true.
Thus, $\forall x \lnot(\varphi(y))$ must be true.
By given LHS, there is $\varphi(x)$, then $\forall x \lnot(\varphi(y))$ is not true.
It is a "Contradiction" here.
Thus Negation of RHS is not true.
Hence, RHS is true.

Here $\varphi(x)$ must not have $y$, because that might make this argument invalid:

$\varphi(x) : x=z+1$ can have at least one Integer Solution, and $\varphi(x)$ does not have $y$.
$\varphi(y) : y=z+1$ is same.

But:
$\varphi(x) : x=y+1$ can have at least one Integer Solution, but $\varphi(x)$ does have $y$.
$\varphi(y) : y=y+1$ is not the same and has no Integer Solutions.

**Alternate Proof of (E2) with I4:**
We could take I4 with $n=1$ to get:
$\forall x,y (x=y \rightarrow (\varphi(x) \rightarrow \varphi(y))) $
$\forall x,y ((x=y \land \varphi(x)) \rightarrow (\varphi(y))) $
$\forall x,y ((\varphi(x) \land x=y) \rightarrow (\varphi(y))) $
$\forall x (\varphi(x) \rightarrow \exists y (x=y \land \varphi(y))) $

Comment: Thank you! I tried something similar for (1) and now I understand. I still can't solve the second one. I think I have to use the second part of axiom 4, but I can't get to the final result.

Comment: I am thinking about using "Contradiction" here too. In case I make Progress, I will update this Post, in a Day or two.

Comment: I understand the first proof, but how did you get to the last step in the alternate proof? I don't understand how the last 2 formulas are equivalent.

Comment: (1) LHS $\IMPLIES$ RHS (2) When LHS is not true, RHS can be true or not true (3) LHS is ANDED with $(x=y)$ which is not always not true (4) When $(x=y)$ becomes true, RHS must be true (5) There "Exists" a $y$ when this occurs (6) In that case, both "$(x=y)$ AND RHS" become true.